# Is there possibility for a race condition in the following circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, race-condition

On this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Gated_D_latch), there is an example of a circuit which implements a D latch using NAND gates :

[image]
Let's say the flip flop is initialized correctly (eg : Q = 0 and !Q = 1).

If D = 1 and E = 0, the right part (which is, AFAIK, a SR latch) will have S = 1 and R = 1 (which will maintain state as expected).

---

Let's say E goes to 1.

S will become 0. If the gate at the bottom left would update at the exact same time, R will be 1 (which is what we want, the SR gate should now output a "1").

However, what happen is that bottom left gate will only update slightly later. Because of that, the right part will have S = 0 and R = 0 for a very short time (which is a forbidden state). Is this OK ?

So to me, there is possibility of a race condition. I might be missing something, that is why I'm I am asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation you describe is not a problem, because after that "very short time" the R and S inputs will be valid. It is possible that both of the latch outputs will have the same value for a short period of time, but that is always a possibility during the time when the latch is changing state. However, the final state of the latch is deterministic and not dependent on the gate delays so there is no **race** condition.

Comment: This is true assuming E stays high until the transient events have completed.  If E glitches high for a very short time, the result may be undetermined.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a race condition when E goes high. There can be a short time when S and R are both low (when D transitions from 0 to 1), but this will quickly self correct.

There ***is*** a possible race condition on when E goes low. If D toggles slightly before E goes low, then there is a chance S and R will briefly be both 0 then both 1. D needs to be stable long enough for it change to propagate to Q and Qbar before lowering E. E also has a minimum pulse-width requirement.